# Using acronyms (i.e. first usage is fully qualified, other usage is just initials) without the List of Acronyms

Tags: acronyms

I have defined a file of acronyms for a document where I needed a list of acronyms as well as the proper usage of acronyms in the document itself, i.e. when the short form was first used it was qualified with the long form, but then just the short form is used.

I am now trying to use some bits and bobs from this longer document in shorter documents that require no list of acronyms.

I have tried initializing the package with `\usepackage[nolist]{acronym}` but this ends up making the `\ac{INITIALS}` throughout my document appearing in black and bold (i.e as though they were not found)

Is it impossible to not have a list of acronyms, but use acronyms throughout the rest of the document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\acrodef`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[nolist]{acronym}
\acrodef{IMO}{in my opinion}
\acrodef{IMHO}{in my humble opinion}
\begin{document}

\ac{IMO} is ruder than \ac{IMHO}

\ac{IMO} is ruder than \ac{IMHO}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmm No I'm sorry that doesn't seem to work? Using your example I get the following:

IMO! (IMO!) is ruder than IMHO! (IMHO!) 
IMO! is ruder than IMHO!

Comment: @sinjax: run latex another time (and don't erase the `.aux` file between runs).

Comment: oh damn you're right that does work! when i run pdflatex on the command line it works fine. It would seem whatever textmate is doing when it is in watch mode behaves slightly differently to pdflatex on the command line. Thanks for the help!