# Do not display one special acronym in list of acronyms

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

In my document I use several acronyms which I do not wish to be displayed in the list of acronyms. [This solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18140/using-acronyms-i-e-first-usage-is-fully-qualified-other-usage-is-just-initials) using the `acronym`-package unfortunately doesn't work as it clashes with my use of the `glossaries`-package. The minimal example ist as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{ex1}{Example 1}{should be displayed in list of acronyms when used at least once}
\newacronym{ex2}{Example 2}{should never be displayed in list of acronyms}

\begin{document}
\printglossaries

I use \textbf{\acs{ex1}} and \textbf{\acs{ex2}}  in my text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: for future reference, check https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149296/do-not-display-one-special-acronym-in-list-of-acronyms-without-using-glossaries if you wish not to use the glossaries package and obtain almost the same result.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following seems to work:

- Define a second acronym list (say, "hidden") using the `acronymlists` package option;
- Declare the name and the filename extensions for this new "glossary";
- Add the optional argument `type=hidden` to `\newacronym`s that shouldn't be displayed;
- Instead of `\printglossaries`, use `\printglossary` and specify the type (and do so for all glossaries/acronym lists except the "hidden" one).

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts,acronymlists={hidden}]{glossaries}
\newglossary[algh]{hidden}{acrh}{acnh}{Hidden Acronyms}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{ex1}{Example 1}{should be displayed in list of acronyms when used at least once}
\newacronym[type=hidden]{ex2}{Example 2}{should never be displayed in list of acronyms}

\begin{document}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

% \printglossary[type=hidden]% umcomment for testing purposes

I use \textbf{\ac{ex1}} and \textbf{\ac{ex2}}  in my text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't actually need to define a new glossary type. You can define the entry as usual and use `\glsmoveentry` to move it to an undefined glossary. See [Moving Entries to Another Glossary](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:moveentry)

Comment: Extremely useful, Nicola. Perhaps this feature should have been easier to find? It is quite useful to use the package to make sure the way you write terms is consistent, even if it does not belong in a list of abbreviations.