# Exclude glossary items from being printed in the glossary

Tags: glossaries

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do not display one special acronym in list of acronyms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31556/do-not-display-one-special-acronym-in-list-of-acronyms)

With `glossaries`, is there a way to exclude certain glossary items (acronyms/symbols/glossary terms) from being printed in the glossary?

The opposite behavior (putting items into the glossary, which have not been used in the document body) is possible by using `\glsadd`. But is there a command doing the reverse?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31556/do-not-display-one-special-acronym-in-list-of-acronyms

Comment: @lockstep, yes, that's the same question and I was unable to find it... it offers a great solution, too.