# Do not display one special acronym in list of acronyms without using glossaries

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

[This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31556/do-not-display-one-special-acronym-in-list-of-acronyms) does what I want with the `glossaries` package that I would rather not use.

Is it possible to have the same (selectively say please do not put this item in the acronym list) using only the `acronym` package?

Comment: For what it's worth: the [`acro`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro) package has means for this (by adding a `class` to an acronym and exclude this class from the list).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible if you don't define the acronym inside the `acronym` environment using `\acro`, but outside it using `\newacro`.

For example

```
\newacro{DVD}[DVD]{Digital Versatile Disk}
```

won't be printed in the list of acronyms, while

```
\acro{CD}[CD]{Compact Disc}
```

will.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document}

\section*{List of Acronyms}
\newacro{DVD}[DVD]{Digital Versatile Disk}

\begin{acronym}
\acro{CD}[CD]{Compact Disc}
\end{acronym}

\section{Test}
Is it better to use a \ac{CD} or a \ac{DVD}?

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]